# how to stop the current included execution in PHP?

Tags: php

I know it sounds a bit hacky but is there a way of stopping the execution of an included script in php ? Giving this example here

[image: end script]

Is there a function or a tiny trick to use to have this effect here ?

**note 1** : I know `b.php` in the example has a closed conditional structure but if there is code after that structure It will get executed.

**note 2** : exit will stop the whole php running execution, that is not what I need.

Comment: Maybe using constants?? http://php.net/manual/es/function.defined.php... If defined constant skip whole block.

Comment: @Ikillnukes does constants has even something to do with what I ask ?

Comment: Yes, you can skip a block of code if you define it, if not you can execute it.

Comment: @Ikillnukes well, this is php, not c or c++ question. And I am not meaning `require_once` or something,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `return` statement in the included file to return to the file that includes it.

From the documentation of [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it.

Comment: wow thanks I didn't know we could do that, that sounds nice, any known downsides to that method ?

Comment: No downsides I know of. I consider it poor style to use include files this way. The best way to use include files is for them to define classes and/or functions that you call, rather than expecting the include file to do stuff by itself. The exception is simple include files that just set some variables, often used to load configuration settings.

Comment: I found it odd when I first saw `$a= include 'file.php';` it's used in places where file.php builds a config and the `return` will pass the value back to `$a`